# UWP install .cer file

Tags: c#, security, uwp, certificate

My local Wifi network requires a certificate (`.cer`) installed on the local machine.

I'd like to develop an UWP App which installs the certificate for me.
I've tried to do this with the following code:

```
StorageFile certFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Resources/cert.cer"));
byte[] certBytes;

using (Stream stream = await certFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        certBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cert);
}
```

It fail at `store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);` with `Access denied`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to add the certificate to the LocalMachine store, which requires admin privileges. Try running the app as Administrator, or change `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` to `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`.

Comment: Nice thanks it works! Do you know where they get saved to. Because if I browse all my certificates with the certificate browser ```certmgr.msc``` I can't find them.

Comment: StoreName.My should store them to "Personal" for the **user that runs the application**.